# The UNIX Programming Environment by Kernighan and Pike

Tags: linux, unix-philosophy

I have recently started reading "The UNIX Programming Environment" by Kernighan and Pike. My objective is to learn about the UNIX philosophy. My question is, Do I need to install UNIX on my desktop to make the most out of the book, or will any *NIX system work? I currently use Linux (ubuntu).

Comment: The linked question answers this tangentially, let me know if you’d prefer to have this question reopened.

Comment: Any Unix should be OK: e.g. Debian Gnu/Linux.

Comment: @stephen yes i saw that but needed more details. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Ubuntu system will allow you to follow the exercises in *The Unix Programming Environment* just fine, current versions of the commands used in the book still support the relevant options and features. There will be some minor variations, in particular you probably won’t be able to use the email-related commands to read your email.

Answer (score -3):

You can't download UNIX to install as is a very old and proprietary OS, all linux distributions including debian based (ubuntu is also debian based), redhat, fedora, *bsd, solaris, mac os x, etc.

All of them including much more have the UNIX philosophy, because the linux kernel written by Linux Torvalds was heavily inspired by UNIX, in the current state you will never find a clear UNIX system from the old days as it is useless today.

Ubuntu will be a good distro to practice upon as its the most well known with most computers and corporate servers running it, if you want to look into corporate solutions i would suggest looking at centos (which was a free version of red hat linux but IBM decided to discontinued it and its EOL was greatly decreased) but due to recent events it would be better to practice Debian/Ubuntu as most companies will start using it as a replacement of centos.

Comment: What the kernel does is largely irrelevant for _TUPE_. Please don’t make this about CentOS (which isn’t discontinued as a whole, and wasn’t affected by IBM).

Comment: Linux ≠ Gnu/Linux, Gnu/Linux = Unix, Linux is a kernel (used in android and other. android ≠ Unix. )